# Python 2.7, декорировать метод

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, декоратор

Есть основной класс:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 'A'

    @mode_switch
    def operate(self, *args):
        result = self.id * args[0]
        return result
```

Есть его наследник:

```py
class Heir(MyClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Heir, self).__init__()
        self.id = 'B'
```

Я заранее знаю, что у метода `operate` возможны 2 варианта действия в зависимости от `self.id` объекта: если `self.id=='A'` то вернем `'A'*10`, если `self.id=='B'` то вернем `'B'*5`. Вот такая модельная задача. Для этого написан декоратор:

```py
def mode_switch(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(self):
        if self.id == 'A':
            return f(self, 10)
        else:
            return f(self, 5)
    return decorator
```

Но хотелось бы делать так, чтобы в аргументах `operate` вообще не было ничего, кроме `self`, то есть никаких `*args` или `**kwargs`. Чтобы декоратор как-то сам определял локальную для метода переменную.

Comment: А зачем вообще уносить это логику в декоратор, если гораздо проще держать её в самом operate?